# Best suited RouteMode for skMaps for custom route

Tags: android, skmaps, skobbler-maps

I am drawing navigation routes with via points. I want navigation should follow exactly the same route as via points provided. To achieve this what type of Route Mode should i set? 
Right now i am setting SKRouteMode.EFFICIENT, but somehow route drawn is different many times.

I dont want any fastest or shortest route but the route which exactly follow my via points.

Please help(I am using SDK 2.5)

Following are the coordinates:

Start Point: -104.98036489999998,39.7435209

End Point: -104.98036489999998,39.7435209

Via Point:

-104.97252523899078,39.74324265487236
-104.96009051799774,39.74316428375109
-104.95895862579346,39.74350251637351
-104.95895862579346,39.74350251637351
-104.94109511375427,39.74377062667071
-104.94064809999998,39.707593
-104.94056940078735,39.71219659344454
-104.94062304496765,39.73016169331405
-104.94062036275864,39.73711087652619
-104.94078397750854,39.74018611509486
-104.9781499,39.7401722
-104.99110221862793,39.74328802758604
-104.99050829999999,39.7428701
-104.98829126358032,39.74547413202817
-104.99693870544434,39.75225473927719
-105.00033380000002,39.7506546
-104.9958872795105,39.754481800432515
-104.99119210000003,39.7543157
-104.98791575431824,39.751256662580026
-104.98734712600708,39.75011009381583
-104.98737931251526,39.74344476945796
-104.98623132705688,39.74330865153693

Here is the configuration:
 prefSpeedInTown- 0
 prefSpeedOutTown- 0
 tollRoads- false
 avoidFerries- false
 highWays- false

Route Mode: RouteMode.EFFICIENT

Comment: The route should follow exactly your provided via points. Please add the code you are using, specifying the coordinates of your start and end point and the coordinates of the intermediary via points so that we can reproduce in the demo project

Comment: Hi Please find updated code